# What does ⎛had you studied⎞ imply in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, present-perfect, past-perfect, perfect-constructions

Can you explain this conversation? Can you explain what might have led to it? Or what might have happened before the exams by the speakers?

> assume that **A** and **B** are two persons talking with each other
>
> **A**: Had you studied much harder?
>
> **B**: Yes, I had studied much harder.
>
> **A:** If you had studied much harder .. **you *must have* passed your exam!**

Comment: Short answer: No. It should be: _Had you studied much harder you **might** have passed your exam_. Or: _Had you studied much harder you **would** have passed your exam_.  But not "must".

Comment: __@J.R.__ Do you __consider__ the conversation between __A__ and __B__ which I have mentioned in the question grammatically correct?

Comment: Yes, that can make sense – but that's not what you [originally asked](http://ell.stackexchange.com/revisions/39e73d4a-aea0-4131-a9ae-9332e18cc475/view-source).

Comment: _@J.R._ Thanks! that what I was asking about, I wanted a comparison from this point of view of the past perfect tense
And what does "__had you studied harder__" mean in this〝 partially〞 correct sentence in comparison with the other sentence ..

Comment: 'Harder' implies a comparison to something. We don't know what without context. From this conversation, the most reasonable context I can come up with is that they studied harder than someone else who passed the exam, and therefore must have passed it themselves.

Comment: All your revisions make this question unclear, since it seems you have something in mind to ask about that really didn't come through in any of them.

Answer (score 0):

I feel this conversation arose while two people were discussing their test performance on the most recent test in comparison to a previous test. Person A is asking person B whether he/she put more effort into studying this time around. When Person B says he/she did, Person A responds with "...then you must have passed the exam".